# Need to close AlertDialog using Adb

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop, 8.1-oreo

i use to run some ussd code using adb android.intent.action.CALL and after read the response i need to close the AlertDialog to run another ussd command and so on .
i tried keyevent but is no good , sometimes it click somewhere in phone and open other apps ..

in logcat i found these intent and classes and i want a good way like kill process or force stop to close that dialog using ADB.

```
com.android.contacts;  [ ClassName: android.widget.TextView ]
com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity
com.android.phone.MMIDialogActivity
```

(without root if possible)

Comment: What about using back button or home button keyevent?

Comment: it doesn't close the AlertDialog , (also i don't want use touch screen x and y)

Comment: I think Firelord was talking about key events like they are generated by USB/Bluetooth hardware keyboards, not touch events.